# Hashing 100 distinct values of range 1 billion

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, hash

I was recently asked this question in an interview. I have an array of n elements. The array has only 100 distinct values. I need to print the count of occurrence of each number.

```
 1<=n<=10^6
 1<=A[i]<=10^12
```

Expected space complexity was O(k) where `k` is the number of distinct values in the array.

For example, `1 2 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 2 3 1 2` ; here `k` is `4`. 
First I suggested using maps in stl but he wanted he to implement my own data structure. Then I suggested using sorted insert for each element like in a binary search tree but that would give a time complexity of O(nlogn). He wanted an O(n) solution. I tried to think of any hash function but I could not come up with any such function. I also tried to think of trie data structure but again I will have to scan each digit of each number thus again giving a O(nlogn) complexity. What could be a possible approach to solve this?

Comment: If you only care about theoretical complexity, the easiest for unlimited number size is to convert the value into a string, and use that.  For 1 billion, it fits in a 32bit int, so you can use that directly, with a modulo for bin placement.

Comment: A simple vector (of size k) of pair value/count would do the job. memory complexity is `O(k)`, complexity would be `O(n * k)` (which can be lowered to `O(n * log(k)))` by "sorting" the array.

Comment: One random comment that may be relevant to you. As an interviewer, my first question would be "what's the worst case?", so I'd expect you to understand how hash tables deal with collisions and why that would not deliver the desired O(n) worst case performance.

Answer (score 1):

Hash table won't guarantee theoretical complexity of O(n*k). But it's quite easy to make such one.

First, we need to make some assumption about values probability distribution - let it be uniform (or else we need some specialized hash function).

Next, let's choose hash table size, say, 201 entries (so it will be less than 50% full).

Next, let hash function be just `hash(A[i]) = A[i] mod 201`.

And then use open-addressing hash table H[] with 201 entries pairs: A[i] or NULL; frequency value.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a hash table is a good solution for this, but I imagine the interviewer was expecting you to build your own hash table.

Here's a solution I came up with in Python. I'm using `mod 100` as my hash function and using [Separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) to deal with collisions.

```
import random

N = random.randint(1, 10**6)
K = 100
HASH_TABLE_SIZE = 100

distinct = [random.randint(1, 10**12) for _ in range(K)]
numbers = [random.choice(distinct) for _ in range(N)]

hash_table = [[] for _ in range(HASH_TABLE_SIZE)]

def hash(n):
    hash_key = n % HASH_TABLE_SIZE
    bucket = hash_table[hash_key]
    for value in bucket:
        if value[0] == n:
            value[1] += 1
            return
    bucket.append([n, 1])

for number in numbers:
    hash(number)

for bucket in hash_table:
    for value in bucket:
        print('{}: {}'.format(*value))
```

**EDIT**

Explaining the code a bit:

My hash table is a 100-element array. Each entry in the array is a list of `(number, count)` entries. To hash a number, I take its value modulo 100 to find an index into the array. I scan the numbers already in that bucket, and if any of them match the current number, I increment its count. If I don't find the number, I append a new entry to the list with the number and an initial count of 1.

Visually, the array looks sort of like this:

```
[
  [ [0, 3], [34500, 1] ]
  [ [101, 1] ],
  [],
  [ [1502, 1] ],
  ...
]
```

Note that at index *n*, each value stored in the bucket equals *n* (mod 100). On average, there will be only one value per bucket, since there are up to 100 distinct values and 100 elements in the array.

To print out the final counts, all that's required is to walk through the array and each entry in each bucket and print them out.

**EDIT 2**

Here's a slightly different implementation that uses [Open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) with linear probing instead. I think I actually prefer this approach.

```
hash_table = [None] * HASH_TABLE_SIZE

def hash(n):
    hash_key = n % HASH_TABLE_SIZE

    while hash_table[hash_key] is not None and hash_table[hash_key][0] != n:
        hash_key = (hash_key + 1) % HASH_TABLE_SIZE

    if hash_table[hash_key] is None:
        hash_table[hash_key] = [n, 1]
    else:
        hash_table[hash_key][1] += 1

for number in numbers:
    hash(number)

for entry in hash_table:
    print('{}: {}'.format(*entry))
```

NOTE: This code will *fail* if there are actually more than 100 distinct numbers. (It will hang forever trying to find an open spot in the array.) It would be nice to keep detect that condition (e.g. once you've walked an entire lap in the array) and raise an exception.

Comment: Since the question is tagged C++, it would be more nice to the OP to give an example in C++.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Agreed, but I think the main question was about the algorithm (and I'm not as proficient in C++). If someone is interested in rewriting the code in C++, that would be great!

Comment: `My hash table is a 100-element array.` It should be bigger, as algorithm will slow down with a full table.

Comment: @Matt The requirement is to use O(k) space. I think you could get by with making the array size a small multiple of k (since that's certainly still O(k)), but in the context of an interview, it's something I would want to ask before doing.

Comment: Thats a good Solution. I tagged the question as C++ as the language I mainly follow is C++. So I m facing a difficulty in understanding the solution. It would be great if someone can provide me the code in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're wrong, the trie would give you `O(N)` complexity.

One insert/find/erase operation of a trie requires `O(L)` time, where `L` is the length of the strings pushed into this trie. Fortunately, you just insert numbers not larger than 1 trillion, which means that `L` is not larger than `log(10^12)` (logarithm base depends on the counting system you use in this trie. I personally would select `256` or `65536` depending on what part of a whole system does this structure play).

Suming up, you will need `O(N) * O(log(10^12))` which is equal to `O(N)` by the definition of `O()`.

Comment: This is indeed a valid solution, with the requested O(N)-time and O(K)-space complexity, unlike hashing which could degenerate to O(NK)-time.

Comment: Thnaks for the clarification. But the point is as I started suggesting something which relied on the range of numbers, he would simply increase the range. I just gave a limit to avoid simple hashing solutions. Sorry for that. But I guess he wanted something related to hashing and collision resolution.